# React Native - Authentication - trigger value to change Auth & UnAuth Stack Navigators

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

Here my App.js

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";

import AuthStore from "./src/stores/AuthStore";
import AuthStackNavigator from "./src/navigation/AuthStackNavigator";
import UnAuthStackNavigator from "./src/navigation/UnAuthStackNavigator";

const App = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("APP JS", AuthStore.userAuthenticated);
  }, [AuthStore.userAuthenticated]);

  return <NavigationContainer>
    {AuthStore.userAuthenticated ? <AuthStackNavigator /> : <UnAuthStackNavigator />}
    </NavigationContainer>;
};

export default App;
```

The AuthStore value of userAuthenticated is computed and updated on auto login or login.

Here AuthStore.js

```
import { userLogin, userRegister } from "../api/AuthAgent";
import { clearStorage, retrieveUserSession, storeUserSession } from "../utils/EncryptedStorage";
import { Alert } from "react-native";
import { computed, makeObservable, observable } from "mobx";
import { setBearerToken } from "../config/HttpClient";

class AuthStore {
  user = {};
  token = undefined;
  refreshToken = undefined;
  decodedToken = undefined;
  
  constructor() {
    makeObservable(this, {
      token: observable,
      refreshToken: observable,
      user: observable,
      decodedToken: observable,
      userAuthenticated: computed,
    });
    this.autoLogin();
  }

  async doLogin(body) {
    const resp = await userLogin(body);
    console.log("AuthStore > userLogin > resp => ", resp);

    if (resp.success) {
      this.decodedToken = await this.getDecodedToken(resp.token);
      this.setUserData(resp);
      storeUserSession(resp);
    } else {
      Alert.alert(
        "Wrong credentials!",
        "Please, make sure that your email & password are correct",
      );
    }
  }

  async autoLogin() {
    const user = await retrieveUserSession();
    if (user) {
      this.setUserData(user);
    }
  }

  setUserData(data) {
    this.user = data;
    this.token = data.token;
    setBearerToken(data.token);
  }

  get userAuthenticated() {
    console.log('AuthStore > MOBX - COMPUTED userAuthenticated', this.user);
    if (this.token) {
      return true;
    } else return false;
  }

  async logout() {
    await clearStorage();
    this.user = undefined;
    this.token = undefined;
    this.refreshToken = undefined;
    this.decodedToken = undefined;
  }

}

export default new AuthStore();
```

The main problem is that the AuthStore.userAuthenticated value even when it changes on AuthStore it does not triggered by useEffect of the App.js.
So, when I log in or log out I have to reload the App to trigger the useEffect hook and then the navigators are only updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `useMemo` hook to achive this.

```
const App = () => {
const [userToken, setUserToken] = useState("")  


const authContext: any = useMemo(() => {
        return {
          signIn: (data: any) => {
            AsyncStorage.setValue("token", data.accessToken);
            setUserToken(data.accessToken);
          },
          signOut: () => {
            setUserToken("");
            AsyncStorage.setValue("token", "");
          },
        };
      }, []);


 return ( 
    <AuthContext.Provider value={authContext}>
              {userToken.length ? (
                <UnAuthStackNavigator />
              ) : (
                <AuthStackNavigator />
              )}
            )
    </AuthContext.Provider>
 )
}
```

AuthContext.ts

```
import React from "react";
export const AuthContext: any = React.createContext({
  signIn: (res: any) => {},
  signOut: () => {},
});
```

Now you can use this functions in any files like this:

```
    export const SignIn = () => {
       const { signIn } = useContext(AuthContext);
           return (
             <Button onPress={() => {signIn()}}  />
           )
    }
```

Comment: This was so good, I solved the issue when the App.js was not updating the state by logout or login functions from another screens. By using this AuthContext calling sigIn or signOut now triggers App.js to update the state.
Thank you so much for the effort!!

Comment: @Gth6 Thanks!! Don't forgot to upvote the answer.

Comment: I tried, but I need more than 15 reputation to cast ;(

Comment: Here you go!! Haha!!

Answer (score 0):

If your primary purpose is to navigate in and out of stack if authentication is available or not then asynstorage is the best option you have to first
store token.

```js
    const storeToken = async (value) => {
  try {
    await AsynStorage.setItem("userAuthenticated", JSON.stringify(value));
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

("userAuthenticated" is the key where we get the value )

Now go to the screen where you want this token to run turnery condition

```js
const [token, setToken] = useState();

const getToken = async () => {
  try {
    const userData = JSON.parse(await AsynStorage.getItem("userAuthenticated"))
    setToken(userData)
  } catch (error) {
   console.log(error); 
  }
};
```

Now use the token in the state then run the condition:

```js
  {token? <AuthStackNavigator /> : <UnAuthStackNavigator />}
    or 
     {token != null? <AuthStackNavigator /> : <UnAuthStackNavigator />}
```

Comment: Thank you for the effort to help me. Yes, the main reason is to change the Stacks of auth & un auth users. So, yes it will solve the problem when the user is saved on storage and the autoLogin() will work correctly as the App.js will run first and when retrieves the user from the storage then it will update the state.

But when I logged out from another screen (storage cleared), is there any way to trigger App.js to change the state or should I use something to restart the App?

Comment: you can use  AsyncStorage.removeItem('userAuthenticated'); on onPress during logout, it will clear the storage and will navigate to the logic stack automatically because the state will change in the above condition. as long as the storage is not cleared the token will not be lost or removed.